# Deleting a node in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

What is the rule for deleting a node in the binary tree? Is there any specific rule when I want to delete a node in a binary tree that is not a binary search tree? I know that one possibility is to replace it with the rightmost leaf node, just I am not sure if it is always the case or not.

Comment: Have you tried researching about the same on Google?

Comment: Yes, but all search results are about Binary Search Trees.

Comment: @TimeaBezdan To delete a node in binary tree, I believe you directly pass it's reference to your delete method.

Comment: BST does not have any rules, Balanced Binary search trees, AVL tree, or their further extensions do.

Comment: @Surya BST has, maybe you meant BT.

Comment: For arbitrary binary trees, there is no general rule for how to perform a deletion. It would depend on the context. Is this a question purely out of interest, or did you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: If there's no implied relationships among the nodes, then pick any leaf node to replace the one you deleted. Maybe you want to take the lowest leaf node. Or the rightmost. Or leftmost. It just doesn't matter. But then, what's the point of maintaining a binary tree if there are no implied relationships between the nodes? Wouldn't it be simpler to just have a list?

Comment: @TimeaBezdan : No rule. Just like you said, replace it with the deepest node - if not a leaf node(use In-order) and unlink it from the parent. dealloc if you're using a statically stypes language which allows memory management like C.